# How to do a max date aggregation over the same document in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have millions of documents with a block like this one:

```
{
  "useraccountid": 123456,
  "purchases_history" : {
    "last_updated" : "Sat Apr 27 13:41:46 UTC 2019",
    "purchases" : [
      {
        "purchase_id" : 19854284,
        "purchase_date" : "Jan 11, 2017 7:53:35 PM"
      },
      {
        "purchase_id" : 19854285,
        "purchase_date" : "Jan 12, 2017 7:53:35 PM"
      },
      {
        "purchase_id" : 19854286,
        "purchase_date" : "Jan 13, 2017 7:53:35 PM"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I am trying to figure out how I can do something like:

`SELECT useraccountid, max(purchases_history.purchases.purchase_date) FROM my_index GROUP BY useraccountid`

I only found the max aggregation but it aggregates over all the documents in the index, but this is not what I need. I need to find the max purchase date for each document. I believe there must be a way to iterate over each path ***purchases_history.purchases.purchase_date*** of each document to identify which one is the max purchase date, but I really cannot find how to do it (if this is really the best way of course).

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that your field `useraccountid` is unique. You will have to do a terms aggregation, inside do the max aggregation. I can think of this:

```
"aggs":{
    "unique_user_ids":{
        "terms":{
            "field": "useraccountid",
            "size": 10000 #Default value is 10
        },
        "aggs":{
            "max_date":{
                "max":{
                    "field": "purchases_history.purchases.purchase_date"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the `aggregations` field you'll see first the unique user ID and inside, their max date.

Note the 10,000 in the size. The `terms` aggregation is only recommended to return until 10,000 results.

If you need more, you can play with the [Composite aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-composite-aggregation.html). With that, you can paginate your results and your cluster won't get performance issues.

I can think of the following if you want to play with Composite:

```
GET /_search
{
    "aggs" : {
        "my_buckets": {
            "composite" : {
                "size": 10000, #Default set to 10
                "sources" : [
                    { "user_id": { "terms": {"field": "useraccountid" } } },
                    { "product": { "max": { "field": "purchases_history.purchases.purchase_date" } } }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

After running the query, it will return a field called `after_key`. With that field you can paginate your results in pages of 10,000 elements. Take a look at the [After parameter for the composite aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-composite-aggregation.html).

Hope this is helpful! :D

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! Didn't even know those features existed. I just needed to make an adjustment inside the composite block to make this work properly: `"composite": {
        "size": 1000,
        "sources": [
          {
            "user_account_id": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "user_account_profile.user_account_id"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      "aggs": {
        "max_purchase_date": {
          "max": {
            "field": "purchases_history.purchases.purchase_date"
          }
        }... `

Comment: Btw, I am going a little bit further and using a pipeline filter through bucket selector for that `max_purchase_date`. Any chance to get some help on a date filter (of course in another thread or complementing/updating this current question)? It is kind of already working the main script but I am pretty sure the the `max_purchase_date` is in a different inner type from `Date().getTime()`. (I am not actually a programmer or a very technical person. I am just having to make this thing to work but I basically don't know what I don't know). I am sorry.

Comment: No problem. I'd recommend you to create another question for that.

Comment: Thank you again. I just created a new question as suggested. Not sure if here is the best place to paste it but if not I will delete it for sure. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57776340/how-to-filter-current-date-minus-n-days-in-elasticsearch-aggregation-query