# How to filter current date minus N days in Elasticsearch aggregation query?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to use a filter over an aggregation result in a Elasticsearch query. Basically I have millions of documents with the following format:

```
{
  "useraccountid": 123456,
  "purchases_history" : {
    "last_updated" : "Sat Apr 27 13:41:46 UTC 2019",
    "purchases" : [
      {
        "purchase_id" : 19854284,
        "purchase_date" : "Jan 11, 2017 7:53:35 PM"
      },
      {
        "purchase_id" : 19854285,
        "purchase_date" : "Jan 12, 2017 7:53:35 PM"
      },
      {
        "purchase_id" : 19854286,
        "purchase_date" : "Jan 13, 2017 7:53:35 PM"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

And first of all I need to do something like a `SELECT useraccountid, max(purchases_history.purchases.purchase_date) FROM my_index GROUP BY useraccountid`, which was done using the following query that was also complemented with a pipeline filter to add a `HAVING max(purchases_history.purchases.purchase_date) < getdate() - 365` clause so I only get those documents (ie. user account) that last purchased more than one year ago.

```
GET my_personal_index/_search
{
  "aggs": {
    "buckets": {
      "composite": {
        "size": 1000,
        "sources": [
          {
            "user_account_id": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "useraccountid"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      "aggs": {
        "max_purchase_date": {
          "max": {
            "field": "purchases_history.purchases.purchase_date"
          }
        },
        "max_purchase_date_filter": {
          "bucket_selector": {
            "buckets_path": { 
              "maxPurchaseDate": "max_purchase_date" 
            },
            "script": {
              "lang": "painless",
              "source": "long now = new Date().getTime(); params.maxPurchaseDate < now - 365"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When I run this query I get no errors or warnings but the result makes no sense. I believe because perhaps I am comparing "banana to apple" when I do the `"long now = new Date().getTime(); params.maxPurchaseDate < now - 365"`. As I am not actually a programer or a very technical person I don't know much how to move forward to bypass and make this to filter the aggregated date properly.

Here is the mapping of the date container block:

```
"purchases_history": {
  "properties": {
    "purchases": {
      "purchase_date": {
        "type": "date",
        "format": "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy||MMM d, yyyy HH:mm:ss a"
      },
      "purchase_id": {
        "type": "long"
      },
    }
  }
}
```

Any suggestion? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most simple that comes to mind is to change your script to

`"source": "long now = new Date().getTime(); params.maxPurchaseDate > now - 365*86400000L"`

where `86400000` number of millis per day.

Note though that according to https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/painless/master/painless-datetime.html

> Datetime Now
>
> Under most Painless contexts the current datetime,
>   now, is not supported. There are two primary reasons for this. The
>   first is scripts are often run once per document, so each time the
>   script is run a different now is returned. The second is scripts are
>   often run in a distributed fashion without a way to appropriately
>   synchronize now. Instead, pass in a user-defined parameter with either
>   a string datetime or numeric datetime for now. A numeric datetime is
>   preferred as there is no need to parse it for comparison.

UPDATE

more generic scripts:

```
long nowMillis = new Date().getTime();
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli(nowMillis);
ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(instant, ZoneId.of('Z')); // if you need zones
def limit = now.plusDays(-8);
return params.maxPurchaseDate > limit.toInstant().toEpochMilli();
```

or

```
Date currentDate = new Date();
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTime(currentDate);
c.add(Calendar.DATE, -7);
return params.maxPurchaseDate > c.getTimeInMillis();
```

or some other java solution might work as well

Comment: I had to change the signal `>` to `<`. As an example I filtered a document which the last purchase was in April 2019 and I still get it when I run when I use the `365*86400000`: `"aggregations" : {
    "buckets" : {
      "after_key" : {
        "user_account_id" : 196
      },
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : {
            "user_account_id" : 196
          },
          "doc_count" : 1,
          "max_purchase_date" : {
            "value" : 1.554887571E12,
            "value_as_string" : "Wed Apr 10 09:12:51 UTC 2019"
          }
        }
      ]
    }`

Comment: it depends on your logic. 
`params.maxPurchaseDate > now - 365*86400000` means include if the date in agg key is greater than one year ago. `params.maxPurchaseDate < now - 365*86400000` means include all dates up to one year ago.

Comment: @LucasRezende if still an issue, there's probably some misunderstanding. what is your mappings? could you update the question.

Comment: I just updated the question with the mapping. Thank you for the help. About the logic I want to include all documents where the user haven't done any purchase in the past year, so in this case the signal must be `<` indeed.

Comment: I think I forgot to add `L` to `86400000`. Try `86400000L` instead. let me know.

Comment: I am sorry for the late response. It worked! Thank you so much for the help. All the best.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possibility to filter the entries with Date Math.

Works via the rest api. Super comfortable.

```json
// GET /index-v1/_search
{
    "query":{
        "range": {
            "purchase_date":{
                "lte": "now-1y/d" // now in milliseconds minus one year, rounded down to UTC 00:00
                // "gte": "now-2y/d"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Documentation: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/common-options.html#date-math

Answer (score 0):

Did you try Date Math? I have used it for filtering index names, not sure if you can use it for dates as well. Check it out:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/date-math-index-names.html